# CAGradientLayer not autoresizing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I added a CAGradientLayer on my UIImageView. I've set the autoresizing mask on the UIImageView to be flexible all across border (flexible height, width..etc).  However the gradient layer that I added on top of my imageView doesnt resize when the UIImageView resizes. Why is this? Here's the code:

```
CAGradientLayer *imgOverlay = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        CGColorRef startBlueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:23/255.f green:171/255.f 
                                                     blue:219/255.f alpha:0.8].CGColor; 
        CGColorRef endBlueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:23/255.f green:171/255.f 
                                                   blue:219/255.f alpha:0.5].CGColor;     
        imgOverlay.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             (id) startBlueColor,
                             (id) endBlueColor,
                             nil];

        imgOverlay.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                nil];

        imgOverlay.startPoint = startPoint;
        imgOverlay.frame = self.backgroundImageView_.bounds;
        imgOverlay.endPoint = endPoint;
        self.imageOverlay = imgOverlay;
        [self.backgroundImageView_.layer addSublayer:self.imageOverlay];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CALayer does not support auto resizing on iOS.  You must implement your resizing manually in layoutSubviews or wherever appropriate.